# xaml specific StringFormat Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I´m binding the Text-Property of a Textblock to a decimal value and want to show (format) it as f.e. "**199,020.89 EUR**". So i need a custom stringformat and cannot use sth like

```
Text="{Binding MyProp, StringFormat={}{0:C}}"
```

or

```
Text="{Binding MyProp, StringFormat={}{0:C}, ConverterCulture=de-DE}"
```

I need to show only 2 decimal places, a space and "EUR".

I know i can achieve the decimal places by doing the following:

```
Text="{Binding MyProp, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}"
```

But how can I furthermore add a space and "EUR" ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to append ' EUR' to the `StringFormat`.

```
Text="{Binding MyProp, StringFormat={}{0:N2} EUR}"
```

To add the converter culture to get commas instead of periods, again you can add EUR to the format string.

```
Text="{Binding MyProp, StringFormat={}{0:N2} EUR, ConverterCulture=de-DE}"
```

Comment: Ah seams to be more simple than I thought. ReSharper always adds a comma after {0:N2} if I start tipping sth :D